# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen que tengo en una jTable en un JLabel?

Tags: java, java-swing

He logrado ingresar la ubicacion de una imagen en una JTable, pero para visualizarla no tengo idea de qué instrucción utilizar para atrapar el valor y visualizar la imagen.

[image: Este es el formulario que estoy haciendo.]

Código del evento MouseClicked:

```
private void TablaProductosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    int filaselec = TablaProductos.getSelectedRow();
    txtCodigo.setText(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 0).toString());
    txtNombre.setText(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 1).toString());
    txtCostoU.setText(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 2).toString());
    cmbLab.setSelectedItem(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 3).toString());
    txtPrecioV.setText(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 4).toString());
    checkISV.setText(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 5).toString());
    lblFoto.setIcon(TablaProductos.getValueAt(filaselec, 6));
}
```

Se supone que lblFoto es donde se debe de mostrar la imagen guardada en la tabla, pero no sé cual es la instruccion indicada para mostrarla segun el directorio que se almacena en la fila "foto".

Comment: Vamos a ver, un `setIcon` recibe un `Icon`, una clase que los implementa es `ImageIcon`. A su vez `ImageIcon` tiene varios constructores, y en uno de ellos recibe un argumento de tipo `String` como nombre del archivo. Ya intenta transformar todo esto que te digo a tu código. Saludos!

Comment: Por favor agrea un [mcve] para ayudarte más rápido y también lo que has intentado hasta ahora

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes la ruta de la imagen lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Image imagen = toolkit.createImage(rutaImagen);

labelImagen.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imagen.getScaledInstance(90, 90, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

Aunque lo recomendable es que guardes la imagen en la base de datos como tipo image para SQLSERVER o longblob para MySQL de la siguiente manera:

```
  File ruta = new File(rutaImagen);

  byte[] icono = new byte[(int) ruta.length()];

  InputStream input;

  input = new FileInputStream(ruta);

  input.read(icono);
```

Ya solo mandas "icono" como arreglo de byte.

Answer (score 0):

```
            try{
            JLabel lbl = (JLabel) tblPer.getValueAt(fila, 8);
            vista.getLblFoto().setIcon(lbl.getIcon());
            
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("No hay foto");
            }
```

Si es que tienes cargado en el JTable una imagen.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.